# pygtk2 on centos 5x with python 2.7?

Tags: centos, python, centos-5

I'm trying to install pygtk2 on centos 5.8 for use with python 2.7

installing yum install pygtk* works only for the default python 2.4. I tried compiling pygtk2 from source but it does not configure  because

configure: error: Package requirements (pygobject-2.0 >= 2.21.3) were not met:
Requested 'pygobject-2.0 >= 2.21.3' but version of PyGObject is 2.12.1

The repos only have version pygobject2-devel-2.12.1-5.el5 already installed and latest version

Has anyone had any luck installing this?

Answer (score 0):

Either rebuild the newer pygobject from a Fedora SRPM, or install it from source in a different prefix (same one as your Python install though).

Comment: and that needed a newer version of glibc. Maybe I can install pygtk 2.10.1 instead of the latest one. That seems to have dependencies met.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Python 2.7 and all other libraries you need in `/opt`, building from source, so they won't clash with anything of Python 2.4.